# Defining an arbitrary function in Django class-based view and calling it from the frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-native

I am making a React-Django web application, during which I had to call a function at the backend and get the returned value (namely, compute the average grade of all students in the database).

However when I tried to [define my own function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/#supporting-other-http-methods) in Django `views.py`, I ran into a problem.

```
class TodoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Todo
    
    def head(self, request, path, *args, **kwargs):
        all_grades = self.get_queryset().values_list('grade', flat=True)
        all_units = self.get_queryset().values_list('units', flat=True)
        result = sum(all_grades) / sum(all_units)
        
        response = HttpResponse(
            headers={'gpa': str(result)},
        )
        return response
```

This is my code on the frontend:

```
    axios
      .head("/api/todos")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.headers);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I believe it is not a problem in the `urls.py` because in other parts of my code, `axios.get` on the same model works fine but not `axios.head`. Also I believe it may not be a problem in the "head" function since removing the `def head` function in `views.py` gives the same error.

If there is any other way to define and call an arbitrary function from a class-based view on the Django backend (without using HEAD, for example), I would be thrilled to learn it. After days of search I didn't find anything that looks workable. Or would switching to a function-based view suit my needs?

For your reference, below is my error message from the browser Console:

```
xhr.js:177 HEAD http://localhost:3000/api/todos/ 500 (OK)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
CoursePlanner.calculateGPA @ index.jsx:232
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
index.jsx:236 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Below is my error message from the command line prompt that runs the frontend.

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/todos/ from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT).
```

Thank you so much.